# In Torch / Lua, how to implement a probabilistic neural network?

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I've been studying this artificial neural network model called [probabilistic neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_neural_network).
I think I understood the general idea, but I cannot understand how to implement it in Torch.

**Does anyone know how to implement a probabilistic neural network in Torch?**

Comment: Is there anyone available to help?

Comment: Were you able to implement it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did in Python, using the `neupy` package.